Defining a loss function with partial output of a neural network using Tensorflow
I have the following problem:
Given an image my model outputs a 3-dimensional binary vector that consists of three features that need to infer from the image. Since, I don't care about the first feature, I need to define a lost function for the other outputs, keeping the first one free.
I must use tensorflow to do so, and I tried the following simple approach:
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    n_feats = 3
    idx_to_ignore = 0
    loss = 0
    for i in range(n_feats):
        if i != idx_to_ignore:
            loss += tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true[:,i], y_pred[:,i], 
                    from_logits = False,                     
                    label_smoothing = 0.0, 
                    axis = -1)
return loss

Notice that if the y_pred has shape (batch_size, 3), I am only computing the loss for the part (batch_size, 2), ignoring the first (batch_size,) of the vector. If batch_size = 1 and y_pred = [[a,b,c]] this function should compute BCE for [[b,c]], leaving 'a' free and consequently the last parameters that lead to 'a' should be random.
Afterwards, I compile my model as usual:
model.compile(
    loss = custom_loss,
    optimizer = optimizer,
    metrics = metrics
)

And then fit it.
What it should be expected is and improvement in accuracy for features 2 and 3, while accuracy in 1 may improve a little due to the tunning of other parameters in the model but remain pretty low and random.
However, my models are not learning at all, as it can be judged by observing a flat loss over the training process, as well as flat accuracies on the different features. I have already checked that the parameters are set to trainable.
I don't know why is not learning. Any thoughts? Can this be done in Tensorflow? Does this make sense?

Your custom loss function seems generally correct for your task, so the issue may lie elsewhere.Ensure that your data and labels are properly formatted and correspond to what you expect. Mistakes in data preprocessing can lead to models not learning.Ensure that your input data is properly normalized. Neural networks tend to perform better when input data is scaled appropriately.Ensure that your model is complex enough to capture the patterns in your data. If it's too simple, it might struggle to learn meaningful representations.

@PriyaT Thank you for your comment. Indeed, after several experiments, it turned out that my model was not complex enough.
